# Encoding info_hash for request torrent tracker

Tags: node.js, get, urlencode, bittorrent

I would like to interact with a torrent tracker in Node.js.
So I calculate the info_hash and I get the good one :
`7cd350e5a70f0a61593e636543f9fc670ffa8a4d`

But to be send to the tracker it have to be urlencoded. The problem is I don't know how to do it to get the right encoded value which is 
`%7c%d3P%e5%a7%0f%0aaY%3eceC%f9%fcg%0f%fa%8aM`

I doesn't know how to get this value, because it doesn't follow the `%nn`format

I tried with encodeURIComponent and querystring, but I didn't get the right string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution that matches the expected output (including capitalization):

```
var h = '7cd350e5a70f0a61593e636543f9fc670ffa8a4d';
h = h.replace(/.{2}/g, function(m) {
  var v = parseInt(m, 16);
  if (v <= 127) {
    m = encodeURIComponent(String.fromCharCode(v));
    if (m[0] === '%')
      m = m.toLowerCase();
  } else
    m = '%' + m;
  return m;
});
console.log(h);

// outputs: %7c%d3P%e5%a7%0f%0aaY%3eceC%f9%fcg%0f%fa%8aM
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. Can you explain why you have to do all this stuff, to url-encoded this ?

Comment: Well, you have to convert each two characters to their respective byte somehow and the regexp and `String.fromCharCode()` will do that. However since that function returns utf16 strings, you can't pass it values that are larger than the biggest ASCII value because it could return a character that ends up getting encoded to multiple bytes (e.g. `encodeURIComponent(String.fromCharCode(0xd3))`). So that is the reason for the if-else block.